Idiomatic term for a commodity with or without a barcode
I would like to distinguish between commodities in a sale environment that come with or without a barcode. Commodities that come with a barcode for example are corn flakes, toothpaste or ketchup. Commodities without a barcode may be apples, screws (if sold individually or by weight) or furniture.
My question, does a terminology exist that would imply the existence (or not) of a barcode on the commodity?
If not, I'm open to suggestions.

I don't think this is really about economics.

Seemed to me the most fitting. Which community would you suggest instead?

I have no idea.

In all your examples, the barcode is on the packaging, not the good itself. You also list furniture as something without a barcode, but in IKEA furniture is packaged, and there it does have a barcode. I am not sure what goods are sold where the barcode is on the good itself? So perhaps something with "packaging" but I think writing "commodities sold without a barcode (from now on codeless)" could also work.

Ok, so my examples aren't perfect. Sure, the barcode is usually on the packaging, not the product itself, but that is beside the point. Am I correct in assuming that the terminology I'm asking for simply doesn't exist?
